# How to use JWT with struts2

Tags: struts2, jwt

Can I use JWT tokens with struts2, if yes, please guide.
We have an authentication server that provided JWT token and my old struts2 app must validate through it.

Comment: I know it is an old post but did you get any solution to this ?